# Authentication Error only in Internet Explorer for High-Trust Add-In

Tags: development, csom, authentication

I have quite a common CSOM provider hosted app. (On Premise, HighTrust) Inside this app I use the infamous

```
using (var clientContext=GetContext()) {

   ...   
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

(I can provide more code if needed, but as this works in most browsers this should not be a code issue)

On the dev machine, everything works fine (any browser).
At the customer, Chrome works and Firefox works. But the Internet Explorer (9 and 11) throw a 401 error:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized.\r\n at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuildersb)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContextExtensions.ExecuteQueryImplementation(ClientRuntimeContext clientContext, Int32 retryCount, Int32 delay)

What could be the problem?

Comment: R u Creating the Context using Username and password or using SharePointContext and TokenHelper ..?

Comment: Tokenhelper (SharePointContext.CreateAppOnlyClientContextForSPAppWeb)

Comment: Allow the app to make app-only calls checked ?

Answer (score 0):

Allow the app to make app-only calls checked

[image: Allow the App to make App-only calls]

Comment: It is. Otherwise this would not work on chrome or firefox

Comment: Make sure that lowercase Guid string like this.. make sure no Capital letter in the IssuerID
<add key="IssuerId" value="983802ac-c7a9-4b50-8100-2c6e2773b9cf" />

Comment: Try to create the Certificate again test it

Comment: issuerID is already lowercase